# How to hide column headers in GWT CellTable?

Tags: gwt, celltable

I really was going to go with a CellList, but the problem is I want a delete item displayed so when it is clicked that item goes away. That seems to have its own problem, so I went with a CellTable, but I don't want the headers to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find you answer there:
 http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/fcd4ad18e2435aba

Basically, when you add the columns to the table:
 use `table.addColumn(Column column);` 
instead of `table.addColumn(Column column, String header);`